# Qt5 C++ How do you access items from a model to check state?

Tags: c++, qt, checkbox, qstandarditemmodel

I have a combobox with multiple checkbox items and I need to be able to iterate through them and determine if they are checked or even more appropriately, as soon as an item is checked, have an event fire off but I can't seem to get the signal/slot combo working correctly.

Here is some of my code:

```
void MainWindow::setupQueryBuilder(Ui::MainWindow* ui)
{
    QStandardItemModel* assessmentModel = new QStandardItemModel(3, 1);
    QStandardItem* assessmentPleaseSelect = new QStandardItem();
    QStandardItem* assessmentVisionScreening = new QStandardItem();
    QStandardItem* assessmentHearingAssessment = new QStandardItem();
    QStandardItem* assessmentDevelopmentalAssessment = new QStandardItem();

    assessmentPleaseSelect->setText("Please Select...");
    assessmentPleaseSelect->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsEnabled);
    assessmentPleaseSelect->setData(Qt::CheckStateRole);

    assessmentVisionScreening->setText("Vision Screening");
    assessmentVisionScreening->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled);
    assessmentVisionScreening->setData(Qt::Unchecked, Qt::CheckStateRole);

    assessmentHearingAssessment->setText("Hearing Assessment");
    assessmentHearingAssessment->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled);
    assessmentHearingAssessment->setData(Qt::Unchecked, Qt::CheckStateRole);

    assessmentDevelopmentalAssessment->setText("Developmental Assessment");
    assessmentDevelopmentalAssessment->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled);
    assessmentDevelopmentalAssessment->setData(Qt::Unchecked, Qt::CheckStateRole);

    assessmentModel->insertRow(0, assessmentPleaseSelect);
    assessmentModel->insertRow(1, assessmentVisionScreening);
    assessmentModel->insertRow(2, assessmentHearingAssessment);
    assessmentModel->insertRow(3, assessmentDevelopmentalAssessment);

    ui->SearchAssessmentSelect->setModel(assessmentModel);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried connecting to this signal: void QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged(const QModelIndex & topLeft, const QModelIndex & bottomRight, const QVector<int> & roles = QVector<int> ()) ?

Comment: What signal did you try connecting, and to which slot did you try connecting it to?

Comment: I tried to follow this but I couldn't get it to work:

"It is even easier than that :). Without any subclassing necessary: connect(this->Model, SIGNAL(dataChanged ( const QModelIndex&, const QModelIndex&)), this, SLOT(slot_changed())); with: void MainWindow::slot_changed() { std::cout << "highlighted." << std::endl; if(this->Item->checkState() == Qt::Unchecked) { std::cout << "Unchecked!" << std::endl; } else if(this->Item->checkState() == Qt::Checked) { std::cout << "Checked!" << std::endl; } } – David Doria Dec 8 '11 at 12:34"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not tried this, but from looking at the docs you have a `signal` for `QStandardItemModel` called `itemChanged(QStandardItem *item)`. What you'd want to do is created a `slot` named (for example) `modelItemChanged(QStandardItem *item)` and `connect` them with `connect(assessmentModel, SIGNAL(itemChanged(QStandardItem *)), this, SLOT(modelItemChanged(QStandardItem *)))`.

That should set your model to trigger the `slot` whenever an `QStandardItem` is changed, and it'll pass a pointer to the item that was changed. In your `modelItemChanged(QStandardItem *item)` function you can then query the `QStandardItem *item` to see what state it is in.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at that tomorrow and see if I can get it to work. Sounds about right though, cheers :)